# Overriding a descriptor with a regular attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to override a property in a base class by a regular attribute in a derived class, something like this:

```
class A(object):
     @property
     def x(self):
          return self._x

     @x.setter
     def x(self, y):
          self._x = y

 class B(A):
     def __init__(self, y):
          self.x = y #the descriptor methods are not called and
                     #"x" is a regular attribute in the object dict.
```

The reason I am asking is because I have a complex base class in which one of the descriptor attributes typically performs a complicated calculation. However, in one of the derived classes, the returned value is trivial and it seems like a waste to have to override with another descriptor and not just a regular storage attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply redeclare `x` in `B`:

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        print("calculating x...") 
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, y):
        print('setting x...')
        self._x = 10*y

class B(A):
    x = None

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.x = y  #the descriptor methods are not called and
                    #"x" is a regular attribute in the object dict.

b = B(3)
print(b.x)
# 3
```